# How to display no Data message in Stored procedre

Tags: sql-server

If @MeasureRuleTrendId value has no data i need to display either empty table or No Data message.. Can you please help what we need to add in the below code... Thanks in Advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspRptDQMeasureDetail] (@MeasureRuleTrendId INT)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
truncate table dq.tt


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #columns

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Tmp

CREATE TABLE #Columns (
    Id INT IDENTITY
    ,Col VARCHAR(500)
    )

DECLARE @RowsToProcess AS INT
DECLARE @CurrentRow AS INT
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml AS XML
DECLARE @Col AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQLUnpivot AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLTempTable AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @xml = DetailCSV
FROM DQ.MeasureRuleDtl
WHERE [MeasureRuleTrendId] = @MeasureRuleTrendId

SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @xml AS XML; SELECT  @xml = DetailCSV
FROM   DQ.MeasureRuleDtl where[MeasureRuleTrendId] = ' + Convert(VARCHAR(100), @MeasureRuleTrendId) + '; INSERT INTO ##Tmp Select  '
SET @SQLUnpivot = 'SELECT  ID, ColName, VAL FROM   (SELECT * from ##Tmp ) p UNPIVOT    (VAL FOR ColName IN ('
SET @SQLTempTable = ''
SET @SQLTempTable = 'CREATE Table ##Tmp ( ID INT Identity ,'

INSERT INTO #Columns (col)
SELECT DISTINCT C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS NodeName
FROM @xml.nodes('/row/*') AS T(C)

SET @RowsToProcess = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @CurrentRow = 0

WHILE @CurrentRow < @RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1

    SELECT @Col = Col
    FROM #Columns
    WHERE ID = @CurrentRow

    SET @sql = @SQL + @col + ' = Events.value(' + '''' + '(' + @col + ')[1]' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'varchar(max)' + '''' + ')'
    SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + @Col + ' VARCHAR(max)'
    SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + @Col

    IF @CurrentRow = @RowsToProcess
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' '
        SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ' '
        SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + ' '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' , '
        SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ' , '
        SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + ' , '
    END
END

SET @SQL = @sql + + ' FROM @xml.nodes(''/row'') AS XTbl(Events)'
SET @SQLUnpivot =  @SQLUnpivot + '))AS unpvt'
set @SQLUnpivot = 'insert into dq.tt   '   + @SQLUnpivot

SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ')'

EXECUTE (@SQLTempTable)

EXECUTE (@SQL)
Print @sqlunpivot
EXECUTE (@SQLUnpivot)
SELECT * from dq.tt
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please vote up and/or mark as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to add this in your final WHERE, if this is a question of performance, you could add the WHERE to your dynamic SQL too:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspRptDQMeasureDetail] (@MeasureRuleTrendId INT)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON
truncate table dq.tt


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#columns') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #columns

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##Tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##Tmp

CREATE TABLE #Columns (
    Id INT IDENTITY
    ,Col VARCHAR(500)
    )

DECLARE @RowsToProcess AS INT
DECLARE @CurrentRow AS INT
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @xml AS XML
DECLARE @Col AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQLUnpivot AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLTempTable AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @xml = DetailCSV
FROM DQ.MeasureRuleDtl
WHERE [MeasureRuleTrendId] = @MeasureRuleTrendId

SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @xml AS XML; SELECT  @xml = DetailCSV
FROM   DQ.MeasureRuleDtl where[MeasureRuleTrendId] = ' + Convert(VARCHAR(100), @MeasureRuleTrendId) + '; INSERT INTO ##Tmp Select  '
SET @SQLUnpivot = 'SELECT  ID, ColName, VAL FROM   (SELECT * from ##Tmp ) p UNPIVOT    (VAL FOR ColName IN ('
SET @SQLTempTable = ''
SET @SQLTempTable = 'CREATE Table ##Tmp ( ID INT Identity ,'

INSERT INTO #Columns (col)
SELECT DISTINCT C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)') AS NodeName
FROM @xml.nodes('/row/*') AS T(C)

SET @RowsToProcess = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @CurrentRow = 0

WHILE @CurrentRow < @RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow = @CurrentRow + 1

    SELECT @Col = Col
    FROM #Columns
    WHERE ID = @CurrentRow

    SET @sql = @SQL + @col + ' = Events.value(' + '''' + '(' + @col + ')[1]' + '''' + ',' + '''' + 'varchar(max)' + '''' + ')'
    SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + @Col + ' VARCHAR(max)'
    SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + @Col

    IF @CurrentRow = @RowsToProcess
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' '
        SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ' '
        SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + ' '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' , '
        SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ' , '
        SET @SQLUnpivot = @SQLUnpivot + ' , '
    END
END

SET @SQL = @sql + + ' FROM @xml.nodes(''/row'') AS XTbl(Events)'
SET @SQLUnpivot =  @SQLUnpivot + '))AS unpvt'
set @SQLUnpivot = 'insert into dq.tt   '   + @SQLUnpivot

SET @SQLTempTable = @SQLTempTable + ')'

EXECUTE (@SQLTempTable)

EXECUTE (@SQL)
Print @sqlunpivot
EXECUTE (@SQLUnpivot)

--Added your parameter with WHERE...
SELECT * from dq.tt WHERE @MeasureRuleTrendId IS NOT NULL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: Just checked this over... At the moment you do not use the parameter at all... As you do an insert into "dq.tt" which probably is not a temp table, you must be aware, that the WHERE in the final SELECT will only effect your output. This has no effect to the data inserted into "dq.tt". If you need this, you'll have to put the where into your dynamic part...